# Use of waitForExpectations Crash SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-authentication

I'm running a UI test where I need to test an firebase phone authentication function using the waitForExpectations API. Currently i'm using two `waitForExpectations`, In the first command working fine but in second command the Code goes to crash.

**Code:-**

```
func testsendOTPAndVerify() {
    let expection = expectation(description: "OTP Send With Correct Number")
    let signupClassMthd = SignupScreen(phoneNumber: .constant("9814012345"))
    signupClassMthd.verify { response, verificationId in
        XCTAssert(response == true)
        if response {
            expection.fulfill()
            self.testVerifyOTP(verificationID: verificationId)
        }
    }
    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 30) { respoError  in
        if let errors =  respoError {
            print("OTP Send ",errors.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}


func testVerifyOTP(verificationID:String){
    let expection = expectation(description: "Check OTP")
    let verfyClassTest = VerficationCode(phoneNumber: .constant(CommonAllString.BlankStr), verificationID: .constant(verificationID))
    verfyClassTest.verifyPhoneNumberAndLogin(OtpEndrdCode: "000000") { response, responseBool in
        if response == true && responseBool == false {
            expection.fulfill()
        }
        XCTAssert(response == true && responseBool == false)
    }
    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 30) { respoError  in
        if let errors =  respoError {
            print("Check OTP = ",errors.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

**Code ScreenShot:-**

[image: ScreenShot]

**Error:-**

> Thread 1: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'API violation - calling wait on test case while already waiting.'"

Comment: But this is 100% clear: "calling wait on test case while already waiting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Declare in the class not in the function.

**Code:-**

```
let signInVerifyUsrExpc = XCTestExpectation(description: "signInVerifyUsrExpc")

func testsendOTPAndVerify() {
    signInVerifyUsrExpc.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2
    let signupClassMthd = SignupScreen(phoneNumber: .constant("9814012345"))
    signupClassMthd.verify { response, verificationId in
        XCTAssert(response == true)
        if response {
            self.testVerifyOTP(verificationID: verificationId)
            self.signInVerifyUsrExpc.fulfill()
        }
    }
    wait(for: [signInVerifyUsrExpc], timeout: 100.0)
}


func testVerifyOTP(verificationID:String){
    let verfyClassTest = VerficationCode(phoneNumber: .constant(CommonAllString.BlankStr), verificationID: .constant(verificationID))
    verfyClassTest.verifyPhoneNumberAndLogin(OtpEndrdCode: "000000") { response, responseBool in
        if response == true && responseBool == false {
            self.signInVerifyUsrExpc.fulfill()
        }
        XCTAssert(response == true && responseBool == false)
    }
}
```